# Issue inflating main activity with older devices

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have an app that crashes with devices with old APIs, which was not the cause until I updated my project for android 10.

I have tried everything I was able to find online, change all the src to srcCompat and changed the Views, I do not know what to do.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_activity_layout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.braian.InTouch.MainActivity">




            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                android:id="@+id/home_image_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:srcCompat="@color/common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_default" />



            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="65dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/gradienttop"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:layout_marginBottom="45dp"
                />


            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="65dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/gradientbottom"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                />





            <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                android:id="@+id/custom_partner_profile_image"
                android:layout_width="47dp"
                android:layout_height="47dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/profile_image"
                android:cropToPadding="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="45dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="45dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

            <TextView
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:id="@+id/custom_profile_name"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="UserName"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/custom_days"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Days"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
                android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                />


            <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                android:id="@+id/custom_user_profile_image"
                android:layout_width="47dp"
                android:layout_height="47dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="45dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="45dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:cropToPadding="true"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/profile_image"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>











            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageButton
                android:id="@+id/edit_home_image_button"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/editbutton"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp" />


            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageButton
                android:id="@+id/main_options_button"
                android:layout_width="25dp"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/mainoptions"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"/>


            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageButton
                android:id="@+id/chat_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scaleX="0.5"
                android:scaleY="0.5"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/heartchat" />




    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:id="@+id/blur_home_image_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:srcCompat="@color/common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_default" />

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:id="@+id/profile_cardview"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="?colorPrimary"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        app:cardCornerRadius="10dp">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
            android:id="@+id/profile_cardview_Background"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/login_photo"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageButton
            android:id="@+id/profile_cardview_backbutton"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/vector_backbutton"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:id="@+id/profile_cardview_image"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/profile_image" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/profile_cardview_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="125dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="125dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="210dp"
            android:text="User Name"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="?android:textColorPrimary" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/profile_cardview_status"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="125dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="125dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="240dp"
            android:text="Status"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:textStyle="italic"
            android:textColor="?android:textColorPrimary"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            />


    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>


    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageButton
        android:id="@+id/calendar_button"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/dropdownarrow"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        />


    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:id="@+id/calendar_cardview"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="-600dp"
        >

        <com.applandeo.materialcalendarview.CalendarView

            android:visibility="visible"
            android:id="@+id/calendar_view"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="375dp"
            app:type="one_day_picker"
            app:headerColor="?colorPrimary"
            app:selectionColor="?colorPrimary">

        </com.applandeo.materialcalendarview.CalendarView>


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/calendar_save_date_button"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:layout_marginTop="400dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/sender_messages_layout"
            android:text="Add Event"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="30dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/calendar_show_dates_button"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:layout_marginTop="400dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/sender_messages_layout"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:text="Show Dates"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="30dp"/>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>



    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:id="@+id/addevent_cardview"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="400dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="?colorPrimary">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageButton
            android:id="@+id/addevent_backbutton"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/vector_backbutton"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:tint="?colorSecondary"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/addevent_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="Add Event"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textColor="?android:textColorPrimary" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/addevent_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:hint="Event Name..."
            android:textColor="?android:textColorPrimary"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/addevent_description"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:hint="Event Description..."
            android:textColor="?android:textColorPrimary"/>

        <TimePicker
            android:id="@+id/addevent_timepicker"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
            android:timePickerMode="spinner"
            android:scaleY="0.5"
            android:scaleX="0.5"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            tools:targetApi="lollipop" />
        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/addevent_reminder"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/btn_dropdown"
            android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
            android:layout_marginTop="185dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/addevent_save"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="300dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="Save"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/buttons"
            android:textColor="?colorPrimary"/>


    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:id="@+id/showevents_cardview"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="400dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="?colorPrimary">



        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/showevents_recyclerview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="375dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/vector_gradientupdown"
            android:tint="?colorPrimary"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"/>



        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageButton
            android:id="@+id/showevents_backbutton"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/vector_backbutton"
            android:tint="?colorPrimaryDark"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"/>


    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>




</RelativeLayout>
```

These are the errors I get at runtime while using a virtual device with API 16.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.braian.smarttouchcouples/com.example.braian.InTouch.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #304: Error inflating class <unknown>
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #304: Error inflating class <unknown>
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:555)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161)
        at com.example.braian.InTouch.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:140)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:555) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161) 
        at com.example.braian.InTouch.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:140) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
     Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "?2130968731"
        at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
        at java.lang.Integer.parse(Integer.java:375)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:366)
        at com.android.internal.util.XmlUtils.convertValueToInt(XmlUtils.java:123)
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getInt(TypedArray.java:254)
        at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:146)
        at android.widget.ImageButton.<init>(ImageButton.java:87)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageButton.<init>(AppCompatImageButton.java:73)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageButton.<init>(AppCompatImageButton.java:69)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:555) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161) 
        at com.example.braian.InTouch.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:140) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
Process 3574 terminated.
```

Comment: In every case, there is no resource with id `?2130968731` (which isn't even an `int`).

Comment: @MartinZeitler I do not understand what is causing this issue since the app works fine with android 10, how could i fix the problem?

Comment: You'd need to see what line 304 is and fix that for elder API...or provide the resource in the package, instead of depending on the framework.